# Display page and picture in one request in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wondered if it is possible to show picture in a view without calling an action. The picture is displayed by using the following Razor code:

```
    <img class="photo" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = @Model.Id })" />
```

But retrieving picture from server requires an additional request.

Is it possible to "deploy" image in ViewBag and show it in view without calling server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to "deploy" image in ViewBag and show it in view without calling server?

You could use the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). But be careful as it might not be [supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support) by all browsers.

Example:

```
<img class="photo" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG....." alt="" />
```

where `src` attribute of the image contains the Base64 encoded image that could come from ViewBag or a view model.